# How to configure wordpress application with simple php application using Nginx?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I want to configure a Wordpress application with a simple php application. 
The directory structure of the application is as follow :

Root directory : /var/www/demoApp/

Wordpress directory : /var/www/demoApp/wordpress/

Here i want to access the wordpress application using route http://BASE_URL/wordpress. But i am not able to configure the web server. All the php pages under /var/www/demoApp/ directory are working fine using url http://BASE_URL/. While wordpress files are not being loaded correctly.

Here is my Nginx configuration block :

```
server 
{
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/demoApp;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;

    error_page 500 404 /404.php;

    location / 
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /wordpress 
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /wordpress/index.php?$1 last;
        location ~ \.php 
        {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What could be wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a common `root` for both applications, therefore the nested `location ~ \.php` block is unnecessary (and in your configuration is never taken). See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

The `try_files` and `rewrite` are conflicting, and a single `try_files` statement is adequate. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

You should try something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/demoApp;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;

    error_page 500 404 /404.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /wordpress {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above configurations. In this case only home page of the wordpress app works fine. Other pages of the wordpress app serve the index file of simple php app.

For example http://BASE_URL/wordpress works fine. while, http://BASE_URL/wordpress/blog gives the same output as http://BASE_URL/

Comment: Is WordPress configured to use the `/wordpress` prefix in [SITEURL and HOME variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)? I cannot see how `/wordpress/blog` could access `/index.php`

Comment: Yes, I configured WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in configuration file.

define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wordpress');

Comment: `localhost` is not correct - unless you only want to access the site locally. These variables need to specify BASE_URL or just `/wordpress` (to make it a relative URL)

Comment: Yes, I am installing the app in local machine.